# Load all items in android RecyclerView at once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm too tired for searched this question in two day's , but i got false answer , I implement RecyclerView and it worked well, but my RecycleView have many items like photo's and video's like Instagram . it mean my adapter will invoke onBindViewHolder for all items to start download and loading image's and video's . but RecycleView just invoked onBindViewHolder for each item's when item is visible (scroll show it) . it's impossible ? if not how instagram can do that . pay attention : i don't want to using database for save image's and video's

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {

    Log.e("position",position+" ");

    thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           Bitmap bitmap = downloadPhoto();//it mean photo downloaded and converted to Bitmap
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
               holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           ));
       }

    });
    t.start();

}
```

Comment: Use Glide. https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html

Comment: Post your implementation of `onBindViewHolder` and whatever method/AsyncTask/whatever you are using to load media. I need to see exactly how you are loading the images and videos before I can help you.

Comment: @Leo thank's for your help . question edited

Comment: Does `downloadPhoto` take any arguments? Like a URL?

Comment: yeah . downloadPhoto() is downloded any photo from internet (url) . in fact i got delay in download photo's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe, you only want to load photos when the item is visible. In fact `RecyclerView` adapter will only invoke `onBindViewHolder` when the item appears(visible) so you can start download photos then update UI when photo ready for you. And you now do not load all item's photo at once, you just load when you need.

ps: If the item's photo url is known, you can use `Glide` or `Picasso` library.

Comment: yeah i know this . it mean it's not possible to invoke onBindViewHolde for all items (visible or invisible) at once ?

Comment: You can load at once but it should be avoided because bitmap costs many memory.

Comment: i know this warning . can you tell me how can load all at once ?

Comment: Are you sure to load all photos to memory?If so, you can load all photos when construct the adapter.

Comment: it mean we can not invoke onBind for invisible item's . thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

You can try embedding the `recyclerview` inside nested scroll view and do not forget to disable nested `scrollview` of `recyclerview`. This way all items will be loaded at once even though it violates the purpose of the `recyclerview`.

Comment: can you give me the example that can help

Answer (score 3):

Although I wouldn't recommend you to use this "solution", since it destroys the original purpose of using a RecyclerView, it is possible to let the RecyclerView invoke onBindViewHolder for every item at once. For it to work, just set the RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView.

Comment: It is true but @philipp-poropat do you know why such behavior?

Comment: @ror because you set recyclerView's height to wrapContent - it loads all views and measures it's height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to load all the image url before scrolling

```
listItem.forEach{ imageUrl ->
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                    .data(imageUrl)
                    .build()
context.imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```